# Read output from diskpart

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I need to read the output from *diskpart* while I'm formatting pen drive. It's my code for format it working in the background.

```
QString exePath = "diskpart.exe";
QString arguments = "/s pendrive.txt";
ShellExecuteW(NULL, NULL, (LPCWSTR)exePath.toStdWString().data(), (LPCWSTR)arguments.toStdWString().data(), NULL, SW_HIDE);
```

**pendrive.txt:**

```
select disk 1
clean
create partition primary
select partition 1
active
format quick fs=ntfs
assign
```

How can I read output to check if everything has been successfully completed?

**I find this:**

```
QString arg ="diskpart /s pendrive.txt > output.txt";
```

But how can I use it? Is this correct? And is it the best way to check if the formatting was successful? Maybe other solution without `.txt` file would be better?

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times; that makes it confusing for people searching this website in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Since you already use Qt, why not use [`QProcess`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html) ? That saves you the hassle with the textfile. Just call `readAllStandardOutput`. You might even check the `finished` signal, which provides an `ExitCode`.

Comment: I had a problem with running this program in background thats why i used ShellExecute(). What's more, when i used it with QProcess my computer got crashed. Is there any solution to read output using ShellExecute()?

Comment: @RanderEns: If you used `QProcess` to call `diskpart` and it crashed your computer, I'm 99% sure it was a faulty argument to `diskpart`.

Comment: I run everything the same what with ShellExecute(), it happened once with full argument list to format pendrive. When i tested it only with selecting and cleaning disk it worked fine. But last time was really strange and i need also running in background what with ShellExecute() works well. With QProcess i had problem to do this.

Comment: @RanderEns You're claiming it with such determination, that I expect you to have a short (30-40 lines!) test case that reproduces the issue. If not, then it's likely you're doing something else fundamentally wrong, and are blaming it on the `QProcess` + `diskpart` combo.